# Show message when no results found in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to use the below code to display data in a textbox. When I enter `a` then all records starting with `a` appear in the dropdown from the database. However if I enter another value that does not exist in the database I can't get a message to appear like "No Record Found".

```js
$(function() {
  $("#Symptoms").bind("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
      $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }).autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.getJSON("/CheckUpMaster/GetSymptomsName", {
        Prefix: extractLast(request.term)
      }, response);
    },
    search: function() {
      // custom minLength
      var term = extractLast(this.value);
      if (term.length < 1) {
        return false;
      }
    },
    focus: function() {
      // prevent value inserted on focus
      return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var usersIdVal = $("#Symptoms").val();
      usersIdVal += ", " + ui.item.userId;
      //$("#Symptoms").val(usersIdVal)

      var terms = split(this.value);
      // removethe current input
      terms.pop();
      // add the selected item

      terms.push(ui.item.value);
      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
      terms.push("");
      this.value = terms.join(", ");

      return false;
    }
  });
});

function split(val) {
  return val.split(/,\s*/);
}

function extractLast(term) {
  return split(term).pop();
}
```

[Enter value existing in Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AVey.png)

[Entered value is not existing in Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsIDw.png)
Give me Solution. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: can you return  "No Record Found" in /CheckUpMaster/GetSymptomsName?

Comment: No i don't  return "No Record Found" in /CheckUpMaster/GetSymptomsName. I am Returning List of records.

Answer (score 0):

I Found Answer of my question. it may help others.

```
 public JsonResult GetSymptomsName(string Prefix)
    {
        context con = new context();
        List<string> SymptomsList;
      SymptomsList = con.SymptomsMaster.Where(k => k.Symptoms.ToLower().StartsWith(Prefix))
            .Select(d => d.Symptoms).ToList();

        if(SymptomsList == null || SymptomsList.Count == 0)
        {
            SymptomsList.Add("No Data Found");

        }


            return Json(SymptomsList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```